# Adding NOLOAD section before FLASH changes ELF base address

Tags: linker, microcontroller, elf, linker-scripts, flash-memory

So I am trying to add a reserved section of flash at an address in between my bootloader and main code that is in its own sector (I am using an STM32F4). When I use the section in code, the elf base address changes and my debugger freaks out, however the hex (obviously) works. When opening the elf in my debugger it looks up the base address, which is incorrectly, at 0x8000000. Since FLASH is at 0x800C000 (and isr_vector is loaded there) the debugger just can't start code.

So, my question is, why does adding this section cause the elf to rebase the address? I use another codebase where this was implemented by another person for the STM32F0 (the same way) and doesn't have this issue. I thought the NOLOAD tag was suppose to tell the compiler not to load that flash section and therefore it would not affect the elf program headers?

Below is an example of how I am setting this up:

### Code

```c
const myStruct var __attribute__((section(".rsv_flash"), used, aligned(4));
```

### Linker

```
MEMORY
{
FLASH (rx): ORIGIN=0x800C000 LENGTH= 2M - 32K - 16K
RSV_FLASH (r): ORIGIN=0x8008000 LENGTH= 64
}

SECTIONS {
/* There are other Sections in here */

.rsv_flash (NOLOAD) :
{
 __RSV_FLASH_START=.;
. = ALIGN(4);
KEEP(*(.rsv_flash))
. = ALIGN(4);
 __RSV_FLASH_END=.;
} >RSV_FLASH
```

Comment: You might find it helpful to put your memory regions in order and make them contiguous, ie: set RSV_FLASH LENGTH=16K.  Also, "freaks out" is clearly nonsense.  Please edit your post to include the exact message it gave you, and also so that your post contains a question.

Comment: @TomV Thank you for the suggestions, I have filled in some more information :)

Comment: stm32s application flashes are at 0x08000000 or 0x00200000 in some rare cases as an alternate but not replacement, which specific stm32 is this?

Comment: Most wont boot (well will boot the no chip bootloader) without something at 0x08000000.

Comment: @old_timer I am aware that the app flash starts at 0x8000000, the elf holds the base address of the hex and my debugger looks up that base address and sets SP and PC appropriately. My issue is that we I add the NOLOAD section, this changes the ELF base address to start of app flash not start of program flash as specified by my linker